# Connecting a chromebook to Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have authorized my local network IP to connect to my Cloud SQL instance from my windows machine. However, when trying to connect to the same Cloud SQL instance, from the same local network, using crosh on my chromebook, when using the following commands:

1. ssh
2. host ip
3. port 3306
4. user name

   I get the following error:

ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Currently, the Cloud SQL instance is setup to not require SSL.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you clarify, you are sshing your windows machine (from a chromebook) which have a MySQL client but you are getting an ssl error right? If so, what does that have to do with Google Cloud SQL on any other component of the Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: as Layo@ pointed out  and If I understand this correctly, you are trying to connect from a chromebook machine outside Google to a CloudSQL instance, right ?  Are the windows and chromebook machines under the same network ?

Comment: @Layo To clarify, I have used MySQL Workbench on a windows machine, which is on the same network as my Chromebook.

Comment: @Marius my Chromebook is on my home network, the same network my PC is on (which was able to connect via MySQL Workbench).

Comment: @relaunched Therefore, you are having this error message when connecting (ssh) to your PC from your chromebook right ?

Comment: @Layo I clarified the original question. I'm having trouble ssh'ing from my chromebook, on my local network, to my GAE CloudSQL instance (in the cloud). However, I can connect my windows machine, from my local network, to the GAE Cloud SQL instance (in the cloud). Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for clarification. It's not possible to ssh into a Cloud SQL instance (from anywhere). To manage your instance you need a valid MySQL client to connect to your CLoudSQL instance (with or without SSL) [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-client#connect